# addEventListener doesn't run

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have this addEventListener on my submitData registration button but it doesn't seem to run it. I also tried just to put an onclick function but it says that it is not defined. Is there any way I can make this authentication run properly when pressing the register button?

```
submitData.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    full_name = document.getElementById('full_name').value;
    email = document.getElementById('email').value;
    password = document.getElementById('password').value;

    createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
    .then((userCredential) => {
        const user = userCredential.user;

        alert('User created!');
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        const errorCode = error.code;
        const errorMessage = error.message;

        alert(errorMessage);
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Where is `submitData` assigned? is your `<script>` running before `DOMContentLoaded`?

Comment: @Dai as an id on my registration button. Im not really sure how to answer your question but the script is located below <body> as a module

Comment: If it's *a button*, is the problem that it submits a form, so you never get to see the result of the event handler if the page refreshes?

Comment: Ah yes, you will need to call `e.preventDefault()` immediately, otherwise `<button>`'s click's will cause any parent `<form>` to submit (by default).

Comment: @VLAZ the registration is in a form and the problem is that nothing happens when pressing the button itself only the contents that have been filled inside the form pop up in the search bar

Comment: @L0caTe Sounds like a `<form method="get">` with a `<button type="submit">` that you aren't calling `event.preventDefault()` on.

Comment: @L0caTe do you have a back end set up? Try adding an onsubmit event to the form and console.log the form data. Also where in the script do you get the reference to the btn id? I dont see that. Can you post the whole script and the associated html?